# how to find the sum of two elements in an array closest to zero

Tags: java

How to find two elements from an array whose sum is closest to zero but not zero(note: -1 is closest to zero than +2).I tried this...

```
 int a[]=new int[n];
 int b[]=new int[2];
 int prev=0;
 for(int i=0;i<n;a[i++]=in.nextInt());
 for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
     for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
         int sum=a[i]+a[j];
         if(prev==0)
             prev=sum;
         if(sum > 0){
             if(sum < prev ){
                 prev=sum;
                 b[0]=a[i];
                 b[1]=a[j];
             }
         }
         else if(sum < 0){
             if(-sum < prev){
                 prev=sum;
                 b[0]=a[i];
                 b[1]=a[j];
             }
         }
     }
 }

    Sop(b[0]+" "+b[1]);
```

Comment: What's the desired behaviour when there are multiple solutions? Just print **a** solution or print **al**l solutions?

Comment: And how is what you've tried not working? What output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: I just wanted to print two elements from an array whose sum is closer to zero irrespective of sign.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
 int a[]=new int[n];
 int b[]=new int[2];
 int prev=0;
 for(int i=0;i<n;a[i++]=in.nextInt());
 for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
     for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
         int sum=a[i]+a[j];
         if(prev==0)
             prev=sum;
         if(Math.abs(sum)>0 && Math.abs(sum)<Math.abs(prev)){
            prev=sum;
            b[0]=a[i];
            b[1]=a[j];
         }
     }
 }

Sop(b[0]+" "+b[1]);
```

Comment: yes the code is fine except b[1]=b[j], but it should be b[1]=a[j];

Answer (score 1):

I have a few remarks, you are using 3 for loops, which can be improved to just 2 nested for loops (the outer loop for selecting the current element and the inner loop to compare with the other elements).

Also you have multiple if tests to check if the sum is now closer to zero then the previous sum. However these if tests can be reduced to just one if test, by taking the absolute value of the sum instead of testing on `sum > 0` and `sum < 0`, which is fine for the readability.

This is what i came up with :

```
int array[] = new int[5];
array[0] = -3; array[1] = -2; array[2] = -1; array[3] = 1; array[4] = 2; // Fill array

int idx[] = new int[2]; // Will store the result (index of the two elements that need to be added)
double lowest_sum = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; // Of type double to be able to use infinity

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Outer loop --> Uses a current (array[i]) from left to right
    int current = array[i];
    for(int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
        // Inner loop --> Check all elements we didn't used as current till now
        int compare_with = array[j];
        if((Math.abs(current + compare_with) < lowest_sum) && ((current + compare_with) != 0)) {
            // We found two elements whose sum is closer to zero
            lowest_sum = Math.abs(current + compare_with);
            idx[0] = i; // Index of the first element to add
            idx[1] = j; // Index of second element to add
        }
    }
}

int res_idx1 = idx[0];
int res_idx2 = idx[1];
System.out.println("The first element to add is : " + array[res_idx1] + "\nThe second element to add is : " + array[res_idx2]);
```

Input : **array = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2]** , Output : **The first element to add is : -3,
The second element to add is : 2**

Note that this code will print a solution and not all solutions (if multiple solutions exists). It should be fairly trivial to edit the code such that it returns all solutions.

Comment: In my code the first loop is for reading n elements in to the array, and the rest two loops for the operation.Using Math.abs yes we can reduce multiple if statements and thank you for you suggestion and the last thing is if there are multiple solution then printing the elements which occurs first is fine, as you did.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in O(N*log(N)). The most expensive operation in this case will be sorting your array. If your domain allows you to use non-comparative sorts, such as [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) then you'll be able to reduce time complexity of the whole solution to linear time.

The idea is that in sorted array, you can iterate elements in ascending and descending order in parallel and thus find all pairs with minimal/maximal sum in linear time. The only disadvantage of such approach in application to your task is that you need to find minimal absolute value of the sum, that means finding minimum among positive sums and maximum among negative sums. This will require two linear passes.

My solution is below. It is verified on randomized data against the bruteforce O(N^2) solution.

```
// note: mutates argument!
static Solution solve(int a[]) {
    Arrays.sort(a);

    int i = 0;
    int j = a.length - 1;

    // -1 indicates uninitialized min value
    int minI = -1;
    int minJ = -1;
    int min = 0;

    // finding maximal sum among negative sums
    while (i < j) {
        int cur = a[i] + a[j];
        if (cur != 0 && (minI == -1 || Math.abs(cur) < Math.abs(min))) {
            min = cur;
            minI = i;
            minJ = j;
        }

        // if current sum is below zero, increase it
        // by trying the next, larger element
        if (cur < 0) {
            i++;
        } else { // sum is already non-negative, move to the next element
            j --;
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    j = a.length - 1;
    // finding minimal sum among positive sums
    while (i < j) {
        int cur = a[i] + a[j];
        if (cur != 0 && (minI == -1 || Math.abs(cur) < Math.abs(min))) {
            min = cur;
            minI = i;
            minJ = j;
        }

        if (cur > 0) {
            j--;
        } else {
            i ++;
        }
    }

    if (minI >=0) {
        return new Solution(minI, minJ, min);
        //System.out.printf("a[%d]=%d, a[%d]=%d, sum=%d", minI, minJ, a[minI], a[minJ], min);
    } else {
        return null;
        //System.out.println("No solution");
    }
}
```

I just realized that sorting messes the indices, so `minI` and `minJ` will not correspond to the indices in the original non-sorted array. The fix is simple — original array should be converted to the array of pairs (value, original_index) before sort. Though I will not implement this fix in my example snippet, as it will further affect readability.